# Send Html as parameter from javascript to asp.net mvc controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass some HTML markup to the controller (please see my **detalle** variable), using jquery, in the action is that I have the problem when I try to send the **detalle**, it said that is not found, somebody can help me?

```
           $('#BtnPrint').click(function() {

                var detalle = "<br><br>";

                detalle += " Yo: <b>" + '@Model.DoctorText' + "</b>";
                if ('@Model.Exequartur' != "") {
                    detalle += ", exequatur: <b>" + '@Model.Exequartur' + "</b>    <br>";
                }

                detalle += "   certifico haber examinado a: <b>" + '@Model.PatientName' + "</b> <br>";
                @*if (@Model.ide != "")
                {
                    detalle += " cedula: <b>" + txtcedula.Text + "</b>    <br>";
                }*@

                detalle += " quien presenta: <b>" + '@Model.Affections' + "</b>    <br>";
                detalle += " por lo que recomiendo: <b>" + '@Model.Recomendations' + "</b>    <br>";
                detalle += "<br> dado en: <b>" + ' @Model.Place' + "</b>, " + '@Model.MedicalCertificateDate' +
                    "    <br>";
                detalle += "<br><br><br><br>  ";
                $('#myVar').val(detalle); 



            var win = window.open(
                "@Url.Action("DetailsPrint", "Reports", new {area = "Configurations", id = @Model.Patient.Person.AuthorId, body = detalle, description = "Certificado Medico"})" )  ;

                ////  var win = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
                if (win) {
                    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
                    win.focus();
                } else {
                    //Browser has blocked it
                    alert("Porfavor, debes permitir que se abran las ventanas emergentes o el reporte no va a salir :'( ");
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend you to use specific report for each case, you can do it dinamically, but, just one for each type of it, because all of them, have diferent sizes

Comment: Definily i need to do it on this way, because it was imposible to adap it as a dinamically report for all, thanks bro and welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you passing JS variable into Url.Action
In your case, you should do like that:

```
$('#BtnPrint').click(function() {

    var detalle = "<br><br>";

    detalle += " Yo: <b>" + '@Model.DoctorText' + "</b>";
    if ('@Model.Exequartur' != "") {
        detalle += ", exequatur: <b>" + '@Model.Exequartur' + "</b>    <br>";
    }

    detalle += "   certifico haber examinado a: <b>" + '@Model.PatientName' + "</b> <br>";
    @*if (@Model.ide != "")
    {
        detalle += " cedula: <b>" + txtcedula.Text + "</b>    <br>";
    }*@

    detalle += " quien presenta: <b>" + '@Model.Affections' + "</b>    <br>";
    detalle += " por lo que recomiendo: <b>" + '@Model.Recomendations' + "</b>    <br>";
    detalle += "<br> dado en: <b>" + ' @Model.Place' + "</b>, " + '@Model.MedicalCertificateDate' +
        "    <br>";
    detalle += "<br><br><br><br>  ";
    $('#myVar').val(detalle); 


    var url = '@Url.Action("DetailsPrint", "Reports", new {area = "Configurations", id = @Model.Patient.Person.AuthorId, description = "Certificado Medico"})';
    url = url + "&body="+encodeURIComponent(detalle);
    var win = window.open(url);

    ////  var win = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
    if (win) {
        //Browser has allowed it to be opened
        win.focus();
    } else {
        //Browser has blocked it
        alert("Porfavor, debes permitir que se abran las ventanas emergentes o el reporte no va a salir :'( ");
    }

});
```

And your controller should be:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult DetailsPrint(string body, int id, string description)
{
    //something
}
```

Comment: When I try it, trow this error

`JavaScript critical error at line 402, column 43 in http://localhost:13076/Medicals/Patients/DetailsMedicalCertificates/1\n\nSCRIPT5017: Syntax error in regular expression`

Comment: I've fixed my answer

Comment: thanks, it solve the problem, but, now I have another, on the view is not rendering the html, any idea of what could happend?
the view is showing like this
*<br><br> Yo: <b>Pepe</b>, exequatur: <b>3333</b> <br> certifico haber examinado a: <b>Lala</b>  *

this is my html on the view 
`<td> <div>
@ViewBag.MyBody
</div>  </td>`

Comment: You need to use `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.MyBody)`

Comment: excelent man, I dont know what will happend to me if in the world doesnt exist persons like you, too many thanks :D